# How to target the style for outlook only in email template?

Tags: html, css, email, fonts, html-email

There is a table like that:

for outlook, it should be width:60%

but for other cilent, since I would like to handle the mobile one, so the width :100% and max-width:650px

The problem is , outlook get the width:100% in the following syntax

```
<table class="table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="60%" style="max-width:650px; width:100%; border-collapse: collapse; margin: auto;">
```

How to differentiate the outlook from other email cilent, so far tried like this:

```
<![if !mso]> 
                    <table class="table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="60%" style="border-collapse: collapse; margin: auto;">
                    <![else]>
                    <table class="table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="max-width:650px; width:100%; border-collapse: collapse; margin: auto;">
                    <![endif]>
```

but it does not work, still getting 100% width in outlook

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple solution is to use MSO conditional to create a defined table size for outlook.  You also have "width:100%" in the inline CSS which is overwriting the width="60%" in your html attributes.

Please see below for suggested code:

```
    <!--[if mso]>
     <style>
        .table {width:100% !important;}
      </style>
                        <table width="650" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="border-collapse: collapse; margin: auto;">
                        <tr>
                        <td>
    <![endif]-->
                        <table class="table" width="60%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="max-width:650px; border-collapse: collapse; margin: auto;">....</table>
<!--[if MSO]>
       </td></tr></table>
<![endif]-->
```

This should get it on all Outlooks, the table does not go above 650px by having a containing table created at that width - and it changes the actual table to 100% width to fill this 650px table.